# When should behaviour that is to be customized in subclasses be put in seperate methods?

Tags: python, polymorphism, overriding, subclassing, specialization

consider (python):

assume global functions: `default_start()`, `main_behaviour()`, `default_end()`, `custom_start()`, and `custom_end()` just as code filler for illustration purposes.

```
class Parent:
    def on_start_main(self):
        default_start()

    def main_behaviour(self):
        main_behaviour()

    def on_end_main(self):
        default_end()

    def main(self):
        self.on_start_main()
        self.main_behaviour()
        self.on_end_main()

class Child(Parent):
    def on_start_main(self):
        custom_start()

    def on_end_main(self):
        custom_end()
```

vs

```
class Parent:
    def main_behaviour(self):
        main_behaviour()

    def main(self):
        default_start()
        self.main_behaviour()
        default_end()

class Child(Parent):
    def main(self):
        custom_start()
        Parent.main_behaviour(self)
        custom_end()
```

I don't know which of these is preferable, but I suspect the second. Is this a matter of taste or are there concrete reasons why one is better than the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer the first solution for one simple reason:

What if you want in the `Child` class to override just the `on_start_main` and leave the `on_end_main` unchanged.

If you choose the first solution, then you just override the `on_start_main` method and your done. You don't have to know or even care what the `Parent` class does in it's `on_end_main`.

If you choose the second solution you have to know exactly what the `Parent` class exactly does in the `main` method, so not only you have to dig into the source of the `Parent` class but also duplicate the code already written.

Comment: Yah, maybe it was a dumb question. If I'm good at refactoring my code the first way should happen naturally I guess.